# CXF - ClassCastException (SEIStub/ClientProxy) in Equinox

Tags: osgi, cxf, equinox

I am getting following exception inside Equinox OSGI :
Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you accidently use the jax-ws stack that is part of the jdk instead of CXF.  I guess the reason is an incorrect deployment of CXF in your OSGi runtime.

You will need to not export the jax-ws API packages from the framework and instead install the jax-ws API from servicemix bundles. You can try to install Apache CXF in Apache Karaf to see how the correct deployment should look like.

To set the packages to be exported by the framework use the framework property org.osgi.framework.system.packages. See also [Apache Felix configuration](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html). Unfortunately there is no option to remove a package from the exported packages. If you use this option then you need to specify all packages that the framework exports. The default can be found in the felix jar in a property file default.properties.

Comment: I checked Bundle 0 in the equinox export javax.xml.ws package. I would like to know how to stop it.